# Do idle Netezza sessions harm performance

Tags: session, netezza

There are times when a Netezza appliance becomes busy with many active sessions processing requests. At these times, there are normally some number of idle sessions. Is it possible for these idle sessions to harm Netezza performance, for instance does an idle session consume a database connection that might cause another pending connection to wait or do idle sessions on Netezza have no impact?

I am considering implementing a process to terminate idle sessions that have a connection start time over some threshold, 60 minutes ago, etc. However, if these sessions have no impact then terminating these sessions might have a negative consequence with no upside.

Answer (score 2):

About performance, I'd say "no"

There are however other good reasons for terminating idle connections from time to time. Examples:
 - Even non-active connections may hold a lock on some object that you want to modify (alter a table, recreate a view) 
 - TEMP tables occopy space, at will be released for these connections
 - there are a (configureable) max amount of connections (I believe that 500 is the default) and you will want to keep your distance :)

We do that every night around 22 - even for "active" end-user connections - since at short "grace period" in our SLA is allowed on the platform for recreating views etc anyway, and servers hosting end user tools (SAS/BusinessObjects) are recycled at that time as well

It is possible for a query to run for a looong time, and now at least we know that 24 hous is an absolute max :)

I hope this helps you

Lars

Answer (score 1):

Curious why you wouldn't just set the SESSIONTIMEOUT property to a non-zero value of minutes -- say 60 in your example -- on the Security Group for these users?  See example below:

ALTER GROUP GRP_EXAMPLE
WITH
ROWSETLIMIT 10000000 
 SESSIONTIMEOUT 60
 QUERYTIMEOUT 240
 DEFPRIORITY NORMAL
 MAXPRIORITY HIGH
;

Once Group properties are set, then NPS will take care of this for you automatically after any session has been idle for 60 minutes (or whatever you determine to be a good cut-off).